# how to submit pyspark job with multiple python files?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am figuring out how to submit pyspark job developed using pycharm ide . there are 4 python files and 1 python file is main python file which is submitted with pyspark job but rest other 3 files are imported in main python file , but I am not able to understand if my python files all are available in s3 bukcet , how spark job would be able to refer those not submitted with pyspark submit command .
e.g :
file1, file2 , file3 , file4

```
spark-submit --master local  --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory  2g   s3_path\file1.py
```

file2 , file3 , file4  are imported in file1 but I am wondering how spark could refer other python files .

Answer (score 2):

#### Create a package (`egg` file)

Using [setuptools](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/)
create your folder into importable package.
Say you have multiple files under folder `mypackage` like the following:

```sh
mypackage
|-- file1.py
|-- file2.py
|-- ...
`-- __init__.py
```

Using `setuptools` you can create an egg file (this is sort of a zipped version of the package)

#### Pass the `egg` file to `spark-submit`

`spark-submit --pyfiles mypackage.egg <rest of the args>`

#### Import your package's content in your Spark Application

```py
from mypackage.file1 import somefunction
somefunction()
```

One more important thing here, if you have the access/ability to pip install things then instead of using `egg` create a `wheel` file and run `pip install s3_path/<wheel-file>`, it will install the package and will copy your runnable scripts to `/usr/local/bin/` or equivalent path instantly making your life easier.

Comment: if i do not have __init__.py , and just file1,file2, file3  and i have crated mypackage.egg but my sparkcontext is defined in file1 and that is entry point for spark , so submitting egg file with spark submit in that case how would spark know that which one is entry file for spark context .

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below configuration

```
--py-files PY_FILES         Comma-separated list of .zip, .egg, or .py files to place
                            on the PYTHONPATH for Python apps.
```

So your command will look as follow

```
spark-submit --master local  --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory  2g --py-files s3_path\file2.py,s3_path\file3.py,s3_path\file4.py  s3_path\file1.py
```

One important note is not to have spaces between the files' paths

Comment: thanks for answering question , along python files I have one configuration file as well which would get read by file1.py , how can I pass that configuration file too . configuration file is text/ini  file .

Comment: Could you provide minimum reproducible example? First though I have: Can you wrap the text/ini in a str variable and insert in a new .py file?