# Understanding the spark-submit API for PySpark project

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm not sure I understand the spark-submit API correctly. The following is an [example](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/spark-submit-python-file/) of the command -

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key<=<value> \
  --driver-memory <value>g \
  --executor-memory <value>g \
  --executor-cores <number of cores>  \
  --py-files file1.py,file2.py,file3.zip, file4.egg \
  wordByExample.py [application-arguments]
```

I understand that --py-files are the dependencies for my project, but what if `wordByExample` was a python project with a main class, instead of a single file?
How can I give to spark-submit a more complex project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to submit pyspark job with multiple python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64004077/how-to-submit-pyspark-job-with-multiple-python-files)

Comment: So, in my example, wordByExample is always a simple Python file? Never a zip/wheel/egg or something?